# Let $(x_n){n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the real sequence defined by: $x_n=1/n+1/(n+1)+…+1/(2n)$ Show that the sequence $(x_n){n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n){n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the real sequence defined by:
$$x_n=1/n+1/(n+1)+…+1/(2n)$$
Show that the sequence $(x_n){n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges.

---

$$x_{n+1} - x_n = 1/(2n+1) + 1/(2n+2) -1/n < 1/(2n) + 1/(2n) - 1/n = 0$$ So it is monotonic decreasing.

$$x_n \geq 1/(2n) + ... 1/(2n) = n/(2n) = 1/2$$

$$|x_n| = |1/n + ... 1/(2n)| \leq 1/n |1 + ... 1| \leq 1$$

So we have $$x_n = 1/n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}1/(n+k) = 1/n + \sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k/(k)$$

Is this correct until now ? What to do now ?

Comment: You showed it's bounded and monotonic.  This is enough to conlcude it's convergent.

Comment: @Crostul Really ? So I can just write a nice phrase that says it's monotonically decreasing and bounded, so it must be convergent ?

Comment: Yes. In fact, if the only goal was to prove convergence, the first line of the proof ($x_{n+1}\leq x_n$) along with noting that the sequence is positive (bounded below by zero), is enough. There is a theorem that states that a monotonically increasing/decreasing, bounded from above/below sequence converges.

Comment: In case you're curious, the limit is $\ln2$, as can be shown with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).